# Weird runtime error (ClassCastException while declaring)

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have the following code within a program I'm making:

```
01  public class Clazz<T>
02  {
03    T[] t;
04    
05    public Clazz<T> methodA(int... ints)
06    {
07      Clazz<Integer> ints2 = new Clazz<>();
08      int remInd[] = new int[t.length - ints2.t.length];
09      return this;
10    }
11  }
```

but when I run method `methodA`, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at Clazz.methodA(Clazz.java:8)
```

Why would I get this error? Of course, the code I've shown is incomplete compared to the huge class in question (for instance, the array `t` won't be empty when checking its length), but I believe I've shown everything that matters. Why won't this run?

**A note:** I am making this with JDK 1.7, so that's why line 7 compiles and works

### Working Solution

---

I decided, for whatever reason, to implement the following solution, and it worked:

```
01  public class Clazz<T>
02  {
03    T[] t;
04    
05    public Clazz<T> methodA(int... ints)
06    {
07      Clazz<Integer> ints2 = new Clazz<>();
08      int remInd[] = new int[t.length - ints2.length()];
09      return this;
10    }
11    
12    public int length()
13    {
14      return t.length;
15    }
16  }
```

Though this is a solution, I would still like to know why it works.

Comment: You are missing part of the code, namely where `t` is initialized.  This matters.

Comment: Does line 7 really compile for you?

Comment: like I said, this is an 11-line version of an 841-line class. If I showed you everything that went on, this example would be bigger than needed. Just be sure that everything compiles, and t is always initialized (I have several constructors, all of which ensure this). Also, see the latest edit

Comment: @Supuhstar: I said that specific thing matters because that specific thing *does* matter.  I didn't ask for the other 829 lines, just that one specific one.  How you initialize `t` determines whether or not you'll get that error.  In this case, I had to assume you were initializing it with an `Object[]`.

Comment: I pass it to a constructor that looks like this: 
  `public Clazz(javax.swing.JList/*<T>*/ jList)
  {
    this(jList.getModel().getSize());
    for (int i=0; i < t.length; i++)
      t[i] = (T)jList.getModel().getElementAt(i);
  }`
which in turn uses the constructor that looks like this:
  `public Clazz(int init) throws NegativeArraySizeException
  {
    if (init < 0)
      throw new NegativeArraySizeException(init + " is less than 0 (the minimum array size)");
    
    t = new Clazz<T>(null, null).clear().t;
    
    for (int i=0; i < init; i++)
      add(null);
  }`

Comment: which in turn uses a constructor that looks like this:
  `public Clazz(T... array)
  {
    t = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
  }` and a method that looks like this: `public Clazz<T> add(T val)
  {
    t = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length + 1);
    t[t.length - 1] = val;
    return this;
  }`

Comment: @Supuhstar: you still might run into trouble at other points when trying to access the array.  You might consider taking the advice in my answer and not declaring a generic array at all.  They are never a good idea.  If you have a generic class backed by an array, then that array should be 100% encapsulated in which case there is no reason not to use an `Object[]`.  Regarding why your "solution" works, I explain that in my response to @DHall's comment on my answer.

Comment: I've found some clever work-arounds for everything after being inspired by your solution, Mark! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the code that initializes `T`, but I'm going to assume it looks something like this.  I've added a few lines that don't change any functionality but which will help demonstrate the error:

```
public class Clazz<T> {
    T[] t = (T[]) new Object[5];

    public Clazz<T> methodA(int... ints) {
        Clazz<Integer> ints2 = new Clazz<Integer>();
        int l1 = t.length;
        int l2 = ints2.t.length;
        int remInd[] = new int[l1 - l2];
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Clazz<String> clazz = new Clazz<String>();
        clazz.methodA(54, 7);
    }
}
```

With this code I could reproduce the error.  The problem here is in this code:

```
int l2 = ints2.t.length
```

Since the compiler knows the type parameter for `ints2` and thus `ints2.t`, this can be thought of as the rough equivalent of this:

```
Integer[] temp = ints2.t;
int l2 = temp.length;
```

It is in the implicit cast to `Integer[]` (whose class simple name is `[Ljava.lang.Integer`) that this fails, since `t` is an `Object[]` and not an `Integer[]`, and one cannot be cast to the other.

### Working with generic arrays

There are many complications from working with arrays declared over a generic type that are documented elsewhere.  In short, I'll say that if you need to have a "generic array" instead consider declaring and using it as an `Object[]` in every way, *except* that when you interact with a client of the class, you either accept or return only a `T` instead of an `Object` (for returning, via an unchecked cast).  For example,

```
Object[] t = new Object[5];

public T getSomethingFromArray() {
    return (T)t[2];
}

public void setSomethingInArray(T something) {
    t[2] = something;
}
```

This is how `ArrayList` works, by the way.  Have a look at [its code on DocJar](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html#101).

### Edit

Generic arrays aside, I don't think you understand the idea of the implicit cast.  Here's much shorter code that fails with essentially the same error:

```
public class Clazz<T> {
    T t = (T) new Object();

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Clazz<String> clazz = new Clazz<String>();
        clazz.t.toString();
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Clazz.main(Clazz.java:6)
    ...
```

Even though there is no need to cast `clazz.t` to a String, it does so implicitly *simply by referencing* `clazz.t`.  Here is the `javap -c` output for that compiled class:

```
Compiled from "Clazz.java"
public class Clazz extends java.lang.Object{
java.lang.Object t;

public Clazz();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   new #2; //class java/lang/Object
   8:   dup
   9:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   12:  putfield    #3; //Field t:Ljava/lang/Object;
   15:  return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #4; //class Clazz
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #5; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   getfield    #3; //Field t:Ljava/lang/Object;
//BELOW is the line that will fail
   12:  checkcast   #6; //class java/lang/String
   15:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/String.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   18:  pop
   19:  return

}
```

In the case of your original code, here is the `javap -c` output of `methodA()`:

```
public Clazz methodA(int[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #5; //class Clazz
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #6; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_2
   8:   aload_0
   9:   getfield    #4; //Field t:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   12:  arraylength
   13:  aload_2
   14:  getfield    #4; //Field t:[Ljava/lang/Object;
//BELOW is the line that will fail
   17:  checkcast   #7; //class "[Ljava/lang/Integer;"
   20:  arraylength
   21:  isub
   22:  newarray int
   24:  astore_3
   25:  aload_0
   26:  areturn
```

Comment: how does this affect the .length object of every array? Isn't that always an `int`? What's wrong with `ints2.t.length`?

Comment: @Supuhstar: The result is an int, but in between the compiler must use the reference `ints2.t` which includes an implicit cast.  I believe it would fail no matter what you did *after* getting the reference.  You could do `ints2.t.toString()` and it would fail just the same.

Comment: @DHall: The implicit cast doesn't exist in that case because you are *within* the generic class instance where all type information is erased (`T` is erased to `Object`).  Therefore it would only be trying to implicitly cast to `Object[]`.

Comment: As for your suggestion for `t` to be an `Object[]`, I'm afraid that won't work, as I do quite a bit of `clazzObj.t instanceof Clazz2`

Comment: @Supuhstar: I'm not sure what you think the problem is there...`t instanceof Clazz2` will of course always fail since `t` is an array, but regardless what you *declare* a variable (in this case `t`) as will **never** affect its runtime type which is what will be checked with an `instanceof`.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say `clazzObj.t instanceof Clazz2[]`