# What change of JLS 6/7 causes the following unchecked code with collections and generics to work in Java 7?

Tags: java, generics, javac, jls

The following code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Serializable> list = (List<Serializable>) (List<?>)
  Collections.singletonList(new Object());

for (Object el : list) { // -> ClassCastException
  System.out.println(el);
}
```

is correct Java (even though the code is suspicious). Using `javac` and `java` 6 it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

while it runs without error when using `javac` and `java` 7.

Is it a language change, fixed bug or a hidden feature?

(Note: Code compiled with Eclipse runs without error on all Eclipse versions checked - Helios to Kepler.)

Comment: In Java 6, `?` is `? extends Object` not Serializable I assume Java 7 is more liberal as to what you can cast `?` to. If you just cast `(List)` this will work on both versin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389994/lazy-class-cast-in-java/15391048#15391048

Comment: Can you comment the line that throws the exception in Java 6, for clarity? I'm assuming it's `for (Object el : list) {`.

Comment: @Peter, well... the above *did* compile using javac 6, so... Anyway, I guess only the actual type of the `list` variable matters, not how I did the assignment?

Comment: @zhong.j.yu, thanks for the pointer! Sad thing they did not spec this out precisely :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're polluting the heap by adding your raw `Object` to the collection (which you're having to do the cast dance to make happen). It's not technically illegal, but it is a bug.

When you are pulling the value out of your implicit iterator, the Java 6 compiler appears to be casting immediately, while the Java 7 compiler isn't. It's more efficient not to cast to `Serializable` if it doesn't need to (since the holding variable is just `Object`), but this behavior is undefined as far as I understand from the JLS. Try running `javap` on your two `.class` files and looking at the code right around that `for` loop (probably right after an `invokeinterface` call to `Iterator.next()`).

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I know my question sounds silly, but I really really do understand what is going and know what to get and read bytecode, and I know even that any such code as in my example should be fixed immediately -- all this is off-topic. Hopefully your explanation will help others. My question was -- **why** did the behavior change between Sun/Oracle Java 6 and 7?

Comment: That was an aside comment in my answer. ;-) Apparently the spec doesn't specify the point at which the implicit cast is required, and in this case the Java 7 compiler could observe via new static analysis logic that you were always treating the reference pulled out of the collection as a plain `Object` anyway, and so it didn't waste instructions performing a cast that was irrelevant.