# Is there any scenario where heap pollution from parameterized vararg type occurs without an explicit `Object[]` conversion?

Tags: java, heap-pollution

I have been looking at various answers and articles regarding heap pollution when using non-reifiable varargs parameters. All examples I have found use an `Object[]` conversion followed by an array element write. The heap pollution only ever seems to occur in this manner, for example:

```java
public void example(List<Integer>... lists) {
    // lists[0] = Collections.singletonList("A!");
    Object[] objects = lists;
    objects[0] = Collections.singletonList("B!"); // (pollutes!)
}
```

Some other articles ([such as this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291696/17556153)) also appear to be incorrect or entirely misleading:

> So now we have a `List<String>` that actually contains an `Integer`, and it's floating around, safely.

The code presented in the answer never modifies the lists themselves, just the temporary varargs array within the `faultyMethod` scope. This [runnable demo](https://jdoodle.com/ia/lhS) shows that neither of the two lists are ever polluted and both retain their original `String` objects (contrary to the answer suggesting they are polluted with an `Integer`).

---

I now have two resulting questions:

1. Why does the compiler need to warn us on every possible method when the vast majority of them will not be converting to `Object[]` - surely it would be better to only warn on the problematic `Object[]` line itself? Perhaps there is a scenario where "possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type" can occur without any explicit `Object[]` conversion?
2. Is the answer to the previous SO question incorrect or am I misinterpreting the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the compiler need to warn us on every possible method when the vast majority of them will not be converting to

You have a variable of type e.g. `List<Integer>[]` here but it can actually contain something else. Yes, there was a choice to instead treat the `lists` parameter as having type `[TAINTED]{List<Integer>[]}` instead, and have this voodoo magic unexpressible type act like a plain ole `List<Integer>[]` when e.g. accessing it with `foo = lists[0]`, but have it emit warnings if you try to write to it with e.g. `lists[0] = ...;`.

But java didn't - that would have complicated the typing system, requiring the introduction for the compiler of the notion of a type that means: "It's like an array of this type, unless you write to it, in which case you specifically need to produce warnings now whereas for other ways of obtaining this type, you don't".

Your human brain looks at the whole thing and reasons about the whole thing. Computer code is written to abstract and modularize and limit. Compiler limits expressions to just 'they are of this type', they don't "get to" keep in the back of their mind: Oh, yeah, this is a `List<Integer>[]` but it's varargs-based so I need to doublecheck if the code attempts to corrupt heap with this thing or not.

Note that `@SafeVarargs` is an attempt to mitigate some of this, you should look into it.

> Is the answer to the previous SO question incorrect or am I misinterpreting the statement?

yes, that 14-point, accepted answer is indeed utter tripe (That's not sarcasm). I have no idea why it's rated like this. It makes no sense.

The primary inherent danger in genericsed varargs is if you take the array **itself** and do anything with it other than use-it-and-lose-it: If you pass that array on to another method*, or store it in a field, **that** is a potential disaster waiting to happen. If you just read from it or loop through it, it doesn't matter.

*) Of course, if the method(s) you pass the array to themselves recursively adhere to the rule of I either [A] read from it, and/or [B] loop through it, and/or [C] methods that fit this definition recursively, then there is no problem. As long as that array doesn't ever get stored in a field or gets written to, it just doesn't matter. The answer you linked to doesn't write/store, and therefore makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That explains #2 clearly. You say "but it can actually contain something else"; my counterpoint is that it is impossible for it to contain anything else unless the callee explicitly forced something into the array argument themselves. Surely the warning should be at the call site given that they are the ones providing the unchecked input?

Comment: No. For the same reason `T[] = new Object[]` isn't okay. The array you get is, generally, _not_ actually the T type. As in, `varArgs.getClass().getComponentType()` is the wrong answer.